# I want to have first row in consol after i write something.. how can i get?

Tags: c++

During programming, I just want to first row in console for example:

**First step:** (in console result)

```
a

a

a

a

a

// this program maybe like this
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    cout<<"a"<<endl;
```

**Second step:** This part is what I ask, I want to get the form below (in console):

```
ab

ab

ab

ab

ab
```

Exactly what I want is after first step, I can't return to first row
just I want to write 'b' but what I know is I can't be back to first row.

So how can I do?

Comment: Why not simply `cout<<"ab"`?

Comment: Does the answer need to be portable?

Comment: because that is not my intention...

Comment: maybe i will find another way to solve the problem Thankyou ^^

Comment: `cout` is not a console. It is a standard output, which is strictly linear. You can get desired output on various terminal implementation, but that depends on operating system (and terminal implmenetation). What is your environment?

Answer (score 0):

you can't modify a console line afterwards. to give the impression that you do you may clear the console and then rewrite the whole output.

Comment: True if the console output is a line printer but most modern consoles provide a way of writing to any line of their screen.

Comment: @CharlesBailey ok -- but how can e.g. bashes echo or a println (c/java whatever) modify the writing position?

Comment: If you now the exact terminal you can print the escape sequence (e.g. in bash via `printf '\033[H'` for a vt320 like mine) or you can use a library which abstracts the particular type of terminal such as `tput` from ncurses, so in bash you would write `tput home` and the cursor position is moved to the home position.

Comment: ok but in general you can't do it then... to me it is a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [control sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) if your terminal supports.
For instance, you can try the following codes:

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << 'a' << endl;
    }

    cout << '\033' << "[5A"; // move the cursor 5 cells up
    cout << '\033' << "[1C"; // 1 cells forward
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << 'b';
        cout << '\033' << "[1D"; // 1 cells down
        cout << '\033' << "[1B"; // 1 cells back
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would have been correct if it was specified that the console is a VT100-compatible terminal.

Comment: yip but in general it won't work.. I can also say do << AFOIASF because I patched my  system to know to go backwards then :D